# Combining Framework 7 & Bootstrap 4

Tags: cordova, bootstrap-4, phonegap, html-framework-7

I have completed the project for the mobile website using html and bootstrap 4 and now I will work on the mobile version using framework 7.

The problem is it possible to move my code into framework 7 and use bootstrap 4 in it? or is it not efficient and should I re-code it in pure framework 7?

--| using google translate |--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to combine Bootstrap 4 with Framework7. F7 can work with just about any css, be it your own custom styles, or Bootstrap 4.

Comment: No. Framework7 and Bootstrap 4 are using many same named classed (e.g "card"...). You will experience a mix of both when using them merged in one project.